# the number of NAs per conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, na, account

I have a long database df. and there are two columns city (10000 with NAs) and country (i have 250 countries). I want to know the number of NAs cities per country.
I tried to do pivot wider and then colSums(is.na(df)) but is not working. Is there an other way?

many thanks
Eleni

Comment: `df %>% group_by(country) %>% summarise(count = sum(is.na(city)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a reproducable dataset it is hard to say but using `dpyr`/`tidyverse` I'd do something like this:

```
df %>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   summarise(count_na = sum(is.na(city)))
```